# How to visualize using python plotly in power BI framework instead of HTML (or web) view?

Tags: powerbi, plotly-python

The following code runs in Power BI python script editor and opens a web browser showing the bar plot:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(
    data=[go.Bar(y=[2, 1, 3])],
    layout_title_text="A Figure Displayed"
)
fig.show()
```

I want to see the plot in power BI visual frame.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your code in Power BI Python, I'm not too sure how to load the plotly module into the environment. I assume you get three bars, to get this in Power BI you'll need an x=axis value and a y-axis/ I created some data using the Enter Data feature 
like this:
which produced some table code that looks like this:[image: Enter Data]

Then I used the stacked column visual to get this:
[image: stacked column]

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! I think power BI doesn't support plotly yet. This is an example code. I actually need to use plotly visual for my data in power BI.

Comment: Power BI uses the default python environment, you should be able to just install the plotly package. I just tried it and had a different error :-) , but get the environment right and it will run look at options -> Python Scripting as well

Comment: It's working fine with matplotlib but for interactive visuals like plotly, power BI is directing to a browser (HTML view) and not working in it's own frame.

Comment: Yeah, I just fixed my Python environment to run in Power BI and found that too, I might have a look at that tomorrow ;-) , is there a render mode for plotly?

Comment: I checked various things but didn't find any, relevant to plotly in power BI. If you find a render mode, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: I think you were right, I've tried a few things and can't get it to do anything useful

Comment: In this context, found this resourceful (yet to use though): https://panoply.io/integrations/plotly/power-bi/